# Event handlers in C#

Tags: c#, event-handling

I'm really new to using event handlers in C# in winforms and at the moment I have the following error:

> Error 1   The type 'DotFlickScreenCapture.ScreenCapture' cannot be used as type parameter 'TEventArgs' in the generic type or method 'System.EventHandler'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'DotFlickScreenCapture.ScreenCapture' to 'System.EventArgs'.

I've tried searching for a way to beat this error but so far, my google searches have not turned up anything.

The line this error points to is this one:

```
  public EventHandler<ScreenCapture> capture;
```

And from what I can tell, this class:

```
public class ScreenCapture
{
    public delegate void StatusUpdateHandler(object sender, ProgressEventArgs e);
    public event StatusUpdateHandler OnUpdateStatus;

    public bool saveToClipboard = true;

    public void CaptureImage(bool showCursor, Size curSize, Point curPos, Point SourcePoint, Point DestinationPoint, Rectangle SelectionRectangle, string FilePath, string extension)
    {
        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(SelectionRectangle.Width, SelectionRectangle.Height);

        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
        {
            g.CopyFromScreen(SourcePoint, DestinationPoint, SelectionRectangle.Size);

            if (showCursor)
            {
                Rectangle cursorBounds = new Rectangle(curPos, curSize);
                Cursors.Default.Draw(g, cursorBounds);
            }
        }

        if (saveToClipboard)
        {

            Image img = (Image)bitmap;
            Clipboard.SetImage(img);

            if (OnUpdateStatus == null) return;

            ProgressEventArgs args = new ProgressEventArgs(img);
            OnUpdateStatus(this, args);
        }
        else
        {
            switch (extension)
            {
                case ".bmp":
                    bitmap.Save(FilePath, ImageFormat.Bmp);
                    break;
                case ".jpg":
                    bitmap.Save(FilePath, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                    break;
                case ".gif":
                    bitmap.Save(FilePath, ImageFormat.Gif);
                    break;
                case ".tiff":
                    bitmap.Save(FilePath, ImageFormat.Tiff);
                    break;
                case ".png":
                    bitmap.Save(FilePath, ImageFormat.Png);
                    break;
                default:
                    bitmap.Save(FilePath, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}


public class ProgressEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public Image CapturedImage { get; private set; }
    public ProgressEventArgs(Image img)
    {
        CapturedImage = img;
    }
}
```

Has anyone ever experienced this error before? Is so, how can I overcome it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `ScreenCapture` class must derive from the `EventArgs` class to be used the way you want.

```
public class ScreenCapture : EventArgs
```

And then (to avoid misunderstandings) it should be named `ScreenCaptureEventArgs`. Thinking of it, it would be easier to just create a class `ScreenCaptureEventArgs` that derives from `EventArgs` and contains a property `ScreenCapture` that's an instance of the class you already have.

Like that:

```
public class ScreenCaptureEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public ScreenCaptureEventArgs(ScreenCapture c)
    {
        Capture = c;
    }

    public ScreenCapture Capture { get; private set; }
}

public event EventHandler<ScreenCaptureEventArgs> ScreenCaptured;
```

Comment: Seems this is not required in 4.5

Comment: Exactly what i just found out. Tried compiling in 4.0 a 4.5.2 project and got the error. 4.0 needs to explicitly say it's an `EventArgs` while in 4.5 + you don't need to. I simply assume the generic you pass is an `EventArgs`